# Requests - inability to handle two cookies with same name, different domain

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I am writing a Python 2.7 script using Requests to automate access to a website that sets two cookies with the same name, but different domains, E.g. Name 'mycookie', Domain 'www.example.com' and 'subdomain.example.com'. My client-side script needs to read the value of **one** of these cookies and include it as a parameter in a subsequent request. Because cookie access in a `requests.Session` seems to be keyed solely by cookie name, I don't see a way to extract the correct cookie's value. Indeed, an attempt to access the cookies using the name yields this error:

```
  value = session.cookies["mycookie"]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 276, in __getitem__
  return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 326, in _find_no_duplicates
  raise CookieConflictError('There are multiple cookies with name, %r' % (name))
requests.cookies.CookieConflictError: There are multiple cookies with name, 'mycookie'
```

This suggests that Requests has been written with an assumption that cookie names are unique per session. However this is not necessarily true, as demonstrated.

I think I can work around this by maintaining two sessions and manually copying the other important cookies between them. However I'd like to know if this is a known limitation with Requests and if so what the recommended workaround might be?

Comment: A cookie for `.example.com` is also valid for `www.example.com`; so which cookie do you want? Which URL are you accessing?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, the two domains are actually `www.example.com` and `subdomain.example.com`. I will update my question. Both cookies have the same name, and are set by two separate GET requests, but a third request, a POST, needs to include cookie values from both. I think the problem may be that I'm trying to use a single Requests.Session object for requests to both domains. Unfortunately the server requires some cookie data from the first when accessing the second, as a form of authentication. The URL is not public.

Comment: I have managed a workaround of this issue using two `requests.Session` objects, and passing the cookies from the first as a `cookies=first_session.cookies` parameter to the second `second_session.get()` call. This allows the second session to be authenticated for the subsequent third request. However I've then been tripped up by a problem with setting the `Referer` header, which I've covered in another question. I think that Requests may be too high-level for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 10):

`Session.cookies` is not a dictionary, it's a `RequestsCookieJar`. Try using the method `RequestsCookieJar.get()`, which is defined like this:

```
def get(self, name, default=None, domain=None, path=None):
    """Dict-like get() that also supports optional domain and path args in
    order to resolve naming collisions from using one cookie jar over
    multiple domains. Caution: operation is O(n), not O(1)."""
    try:
        return self._find_no_duplicates(name, domain, path)
    except KeyError:
        return default
```

For your code, this would mean changing to:

```
value = session.cookies.get("mycookie", domain=relevant_domain)
```

As for requests, we know that cookie names aren't unique. =)