# Python3-Requests how do I set multiple cookies with the same name?

Tags: python, python-requests

I figured out that I have a problem with setting cookies. Basically, I want to set two cookies with the same name and I wrote the codes as below:

```
import requests


ses = requests.Session()
ses.cookie.set(name='JSESSIONID', value='1')
ses.cookie.set(name='JSESSIONID', value='2')
print(ses.cookies.items())
```

and the result is

```
[('JSESSIONID', '2')]
```

It is seems that the first cookie with value '1' is overwritten by the second one whose value is '2'. I learnt from this thread:[Requests - inability to handle two cookies with same name, different domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27586779/requests-inability-to-handle-two-cookies-with-same-name-different-domain) that cookie names in RequestsCookieJar aren't unique.

Is there a way to set mutiple cookies with the same name using requests?

Update:
I checked the header of request packet in my browser. there really exist two cookie values with the same name as the pic shows below:
[request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDCWa.png)

Comment: **Why** do you want to set two cookies with the same name? Your browser would never do this.

Comment: Browser will ignore same name cookies

Comment: Cookies are unique for a given domain name and path. I'm *guessing* that your browser has cookies for the main domain and the subdomain, or for two parent paths that both match. You'll have to provide the same in your CookieJar.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. I've tried to add cookies with the same name in different paths and it works fine.  again, thanks.